# shc & gcc : Any use for the *.x.c. file that's created?

Tags: bash-scripting, compile, gcc

shc for "compiling" bash scripts, I end up with two files.  One is obscured version of my bash script which works great, I also get an intermediate file *.x.c..  I say it this way because I've read, shc first creates the *.x.c. then creates the executable.

Question is:
Does shc call gcc to "compile" the *.x.c. file ?

Because if I run gcc myself on the *.x.c. file and compare (cmp) it to the shc executable it's indicated as differing somehow..

I guess I'm wondering if there's really any use for that *.x.c. file ?